# Call JS onsubmit only when form is valid

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, forms, validation, bootstrap-4

I'm new with JS.
I have a bootstrap form and using validation, like this:

```
<form class="needs-validation" novalidate onsubmit="myFunction();">
            <div class="form-group row col-sm-3">
                <label for="exampleInput">Value</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInput" placeholder="Enter value" required>
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                    Value required
                </div>
            </div>
</form>
```

and JS code:

```
    <script>
        (function() {
            'use strict';
            window.addEventListener('load', function() {
                // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
                var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
                // Loop over them and prevent submission
                var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) {
                    form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
                        if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
                            event.preventDefault();
                            event.stopPropagation();
                        }
                        form.classList.add('was-validated');
                    }, false);
                });
            }, false);
        })();
    </script>
```

Validation works fine but myFunction() called always, when form invalid and when valid.

How could I force myFunction() to be called only when form is valid?

Comment: Remove the inline javascript and call the function inside the eventlistener, only `if (form.checkValidity() === true)`

Comment: @bambam Yes, that's it. So dumb question. Thanks a lot.